# Visual Studio 2015 different setting's values in experimental and normal instances

Tags: visual-studio-2015, settings, visual-studio-extensions

I was debugging an extension, that was working in experimental instance, but not in normal instance.

The reason to it was as follows: it was parsing all *.visualsettings files it can get, making a dictionary of keyboard shortcuts' scope definitions. The failing part was

```
if (!this.scopeDefinitions.ContainsKey(id))
{
    scopeDefinitions.Add(id, name);
}
Debug.Assert(this.scopeDefinitions[id] == name, "this.scopeDefinitions[id] == name");
```

Obviously, if the key is present already but has a different value, assertion will fail.

It was doing ok in experimental instance, because CurrentSettings.vssettings for experimental instance contains

`<Scope Name="`**`XAML UI Designer`**`" ID="{E9B8485C-1217-4277-9ED6-C825A5AC1968}"/>`

but for normal instance it is

`<Scope Name="`**`XAML Designer`**`" ID="{E9B8485C-1217-4277-9ED6-C825A5AC1968}"/>`

I suppose, default settings are taken from  General.vssettings, where "XAML UI Designer" is used. I've searched through Visual Studio update 3 full ISO vssettings files, everywhere is "XAML UI Designer".

When all "XAML Designer" occurrences in current settings file are changed to "XAML UI Designer", Visual Studio changes them back (except, it leaves `<ToolsOptionsCategory name="XAML UI Designer"...` alongside `<ToolsOptionsCategory name="XAML Designer"...`). Basically VS is saying: your settings file is wrong, here, I fixed it. But what about its own default file?

The question is: is it Visual Studio's bug? This inconsistency is obstructive, since "XAML UI Designer" goes to the settings of experimental instance. And who knows, how many more things of such kind are out there.

They say "A man should build a house, plant a tree, father a son, splat a bug in Visual Studio". So, 3 to go?